# What is the most lean/performant way to clear Arrays in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection

I'm rapidly filling and emptying a rather large array as a buffer during batch processing, and I'd like to prevent memory leaks and maximize speed during these operations.

Currently, I fill the array and then empty it by:

```
a = []
```

I've just recently picked up Ruby to tweak a 3rd-party tool, so I don't know how its Garbage Collection works. Is this the best way to clear the array, or should I instead be invoking

```
a.clear
```

Comment: GC in Ruby..? *Challenging*..

Comment: @ArupRakshit So does that imply I should be explicitly clearing, instead of orphaning the object reference and waiting for GC?

Comment: There is a way.. But I don't know how trustful it is.. One moment, I am giving you a link. Check this [`WeakRef`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Ruby internals so I won't fully answer the question, but I will say this: `a = []` **assigns a new array** to `a`, whereas `a.clear` modifies the array **in place**. You're probably better off calling `a.clear` as you won't need to wait for the GC and you won't incur the overhead of instantiating a new array.

Comment: @fbonetti Is correct. `#clear` method, will just clear the elements from the *array*, but if you really want to GCed `a`, may be take a look at the link, I have given above.

Comment: Great overview of the GC [Here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc)

Comment: @fbonetti I don't really care whether I end up with the same memory reference after clearing -- I just need to get rid of the old stuff and have a clean array for new data. But clear seems like the way to go.

Comment: @ArupRakshit WeakRef seems like it will GC objects which still have references (which I need to guarantee will NOT happen). That is useful functionality, though -- thanks for the link!

Comment: Humm.. I never used that.. Your GC term actually misleading me, against your intention..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Oh, sorry. I was just inquiring about whether the orphaned memory I create when re-assigning a would be GCed efficiently (so as not to create a memory leak or accumulate large chunks of memory unnecessarily).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Array#clear is Clearly Faster

Using [Array#clear](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-clear) seems to be significantly faster, according to my benchmarks under MRI Ruby 2.1.2. See benchmark code and results below.

#### Benchmarking Code

```
require 'benchmark'

i = 10_000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x| 
  x.report(:literal) { i.times do a = Array.new(i); a = []  end }
  x.report(:clear)   { i.times do a = Array.new(i); a.clear end }
end
```

#### Benchmarking Results

```
Rehearsal -------------------------------------------
literal   0.130000   0.110000   0.240000 (  0.238041)
clear     0.030000   0.010000   0.040000 (  0.026735)
---------------------------------- total: 0.280000sec

              user     system      total        real
literal   0.110000   0.100000   0.210000 (  0.217941)
clear     0.030000   0.000000   0.030000 (  0.025402)
```

Comment: Excellent -- I'll go with clear for now, then. Thanks for including the benchmark, too! That's exactly the kind of answer I was hoping for :)

Comment: can you do `a = nil` instead of `a = []` and run your *benchmark*. What's the point to use `a = []` instead of `nil` ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit the OP wanted to reuse the same variable with a new set of data as an `Array` so it would then have to be `a =nil; a=[]`

Comment: Your code re-assigns the array each time in both cases - that is _not_ using the `clear` properly - I guess the point of using `clear` is to **reuse** the array

Comment: @UriAgassi Well he's creating an array of size i each time and then clearing it via the two methods. He's not filling it with actual data, but I assume the memory allocation that goes on in that benchmark is representative of what will happen when I actually fill the array. I also don't care whether I reuse the array -- I just need a to be an empty array after the operation.

Comment: But that's the point - in this test you never reuse 'a' - you might as well not call _anything_ on 'a' since you are recreating it again as you fill it up... A better test would be to actually _fill_ the array ('a << i')

Comment: @UriAgassi You clearly don't understand what the OP was asking, nor are you clear on why *filling* the array with anything but nils is irrelevant to what is being measured here. The question is about *garbage collection*, and it's clearly more efficient to garbage collect a cleared array than an uncleared array of significant size. If you are still puzzled by these results after running your own benchmarks, please move your questions to chat or to a new, related question.